# How to force page refresh for Instagram in-app web browser?

Tags: html, caching, instagram, refresh, instagram-api

I have a link in my Instagram bio to a page on my website. I update that page frequently (every few days). However, no matter how hard I try I can NOT get the page to update when being viewed within the Instagram in-app web browser (which is the only place people will be viewing it anyway).
The page updates when viewing in a regular web browser, on computer or mobile - in all the browsers I've tried. So the update is working, just Instagram seems to always load a cached version.

I've tried adding, with no effect:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

This is the page: https://andreaalice.com/links.html

Tools like Linktree (https://linktr.ee) which are specifically design for Instagram links always update instantly - so it's obviously possible to override Instagram's caching. But I can't figure out what Linktree is doing that I'm not.

This is my Linktree page, for reference: https://linktr.ee/andreaalice.nz
I've never had any problems with that updating.

Does anyone have an other suggestions for forcing a page refresh that Instagram won't ignore??

Comment: Did you find any solution for that? I've tried different things too but nothing seems to help.

Comment: No, have not found a solution yet. I will post an update here if I ever do.

Comment: You could try adding a header to your HTML response of `Cache-Control: no-cache`. The meta tag wouldn't have any effect on the caching of the page.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I never found a solution, but this problem seems to have solved itself. I guess Instagram changed something at their end.